# How can I change the base directory containing contents of .R files when initiating R-studio session?

Tags: r, centos, rstudio-server

I'd like to ask about setting of Rtudio.

I'm using Rstudio based on Centos server.

I know that contents of .R files in ~/.local/share/rstudio/sources/XXXXX directories.

When there is some crash on a session, the new directories are made, and newly made source codes are saved on that directory.

But, sometimes, the new session load previous sources directory. so I have to load .R codes from diverse directories. It is quite uncomfortable.

.R files on Directories are changed:

[image]

I couldn't find any way to force the directory.

How can I force the loaded sources directory?